# Web scraping with page that updates with scrolling

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing web scraping with beautifulsoup for this page 
https://readwrite.com/category/fintech/

Here is the code and it is going well:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request 
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

#sending request
url = 'https://readwrite.com/category/fintech/'
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()


#reading the request
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib') 

#get the body of the request
soup = soup.body
titles = []

#for loop through the scrapped script
for content in soup.select('article'):
    header = content.find("header", {"class": "article-header"})
    title = header.find("h2", {"class":"title"}).text
    titles.append(title)

print(titles)
```

**The problem** is that it gets me only 8 headers because the page by default load only 8 but if you scroll it updates and shows more news.

I want to scrap more articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you can do to parse all the titles from that page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request 
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen


page_no = 0
page_link = "https://readwrite.com/category/fintech/?paged1={}"

while True:
    page_no+=1
    res = urllib.request.Request(page_link.format(page_no))
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
    container = soup.select('article')
    if len(container)<=1:break 

    for content in container:
        title = content.select_one(".title a").text
        print(title)
```

Comment: Did you try the script @tarek hassan? What's your feedback?

Comment: It didn't work but worked after I made simple edits, Should I edit the answer? (I am new to Stackoverflow)

Comment: In that case you need to re-edit to import the correct module, as in `from urllib.request import Request,urlopen`.

Answer (score 0):

As you scroll down, that page making xhr request to load more articles, as the request done, the javascript appends the new data after the already loaded ones. (that's technique called infinite scrolling)
 If you take a look on the network tab in the browser, you can see it's making request for these urls:
https://readwrite.com/category/fintech/?paged1=2
https://readwrite.com/category/fintech/?paged1=3
etc.

So you just have to incrementally scrap these urls.